# Postgres performance on triggering function to update updated_at vs updating using SQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a Postgres table that will be heavily updated.

Usually, for other tables, I have a function to stamp timestamp of the `updated_at` column which will trigger for every update operation.

Since this table will be heavily updated and I also have an alternate option to manually updated the `updated_at` of this table using query.

Meaning instead of just `update this_table set x=1;`, I can make it `update this_table set x=1, updated_at = now();`.

Is there any differences in performance between these two options? Which one is the right/recommended approach?

Comment: 1) The only way to really know is to test it in your setup. 2) FYI, the value of `now()` does not change in a transaction, so if you are wrapping multiple updates in a single transaction `updated_at` will be the same for all of them.  See [Current date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) for more information.

Comment: This is something you can measure yourself, just check the query plans using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for the update statements. (these will be executed)

Comment: @FrankHeikens Query plans do not include trigger functions, do they?

Comment: @Bergi: When using VERBOSE the trigger will pop up in the query plan. And if there is a difference in performance, you should be able to see it as well

Comment: Using a trigger will probably be slightly slower than a direct update from the query, but the difference might not matter. Improved maintainability due to consistency of design/implementation is often more important than slight differences in performance.